# Output not what expected when setting up ruby with rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm

I've just tried to setup RVM on macOS but getting a strange output when confirming whether the installation has worked.

Specifically, when I do:

```
which gem
```

I get:

```
gem () {
\typeset result
(
    \typeset rvmrc
    rvm_rvmrc_files=("/etc/rvmrc" "$HOME/.rvmrc")
    if [[ -n "${rvm_prefix:-}" ]] && ! [[ "$HOME/.rvmrc" -ef "${rvm_prefix}/.rvmrc" ]]
    then
        rvm_rvmrc_files+=("${rvm_prefix}/.rvmrc")
    fi
    for rvmrc in "${rvm_rvmrc_files[@]}"
    do
        [[ -s "${rvmrc}" ]] && source "${rvmrc}" || true
    done
    unset rvm_rvmrc_files
    command gem "$@"
) || result=$?
hash -r
return ${result:-0}
}
```

Not sure why it's doing that. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: That's normal behavior for RVM. It loads `gem` as a shell function so it can perform internal logic when calling the command. You can tell because it's returning a shell function named `gem()`.

Comment: OK, great, thanks!

Comment: If you don't like RVM's approach, you might want to check out rbenv: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv